# How Do Vector drawing applications do this?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

In Illustrator, you can drag a rectangle and it will select all objects in it. It does beyond a bounding box test since it ensures its touching an actual part of the polygon. How does it efficiently do this then? (A C or C++ implementation would be preferable)

Thanks

Comment: Does it select all objects that are fully inside the rectangle? If so, then you could quickly prune by the 2-d "center of mass" or whatever you think is the center, I think. I do not fully understand the question though. It seems like a bounding box can still be of help. Also, how many objects should this work for fast enough? Can it be capped at 100, 1000, 10000, etc. or no limit?

Comment: Can you elaborate please, what's the input and output? Also, what 'ensres' means?

Comment: Input = rectangle and list of closed curves. Output = curves intersecting the rectangle. Ensres = ensures.

Comment: @Potato, are we talking about polygonal objects only, and/or splines as well?

Comment: yea, what he said, by closed curves, this means list of ordered verticies

Comment: Well think of it as the splines being part of the verticies since I pre interpolate the control points

Comment: If polygons are not convex, a convex hull might be of help - can be pre-computed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if any part of polygon P is within a rectangle R, then you can do this:

- If any vertex of P is within R, then return TRUE;
- If any vertex of R is within P, then return TRUE;
- If any edge of P (line between adjacent vertexes) intersects an edge of R, then return TRUE.
- Otherwise, return FALSE.

Comment: How would this look like as a function? Thanks

Comment: @Jex: Well, the primitives you're going to need are a point-lies-within-bounding-box test, and a line-segment-intersection-test (the first is trivial and the second is easy to search for).  Testing if a point lies within a polygon is the hardest part - one way to do it is test if a line from the point to the bounding box of the polygon crosses an edge of the polygon an even or odd number of times.

Comment: I have the point in poly one and point in rect one, I guess all thats left is to find the intersection one. Thanks

Comment: Jex, so you to select when there is ANY or FULL intersection? What about a spline, the ends of which do not intersect, but the middle part does? This would correspond to the third bulleted item by caf.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just construct the intersection of the rectangle with the object (a function which programs like Illustrator already have for many other purposes) and check that it's non-empty. More efficient algorithms are available (see caf's answer), but mine has the one advantage that it requires no additional code.